# My dedicated server won't startup

Tags: debian, root, dedicated-server, gameserver, helpdesk

I tried almost everything (I am with soyoustart) but it just won't boot, I got this message from the soyoustart team, they won't help me since it's software related. (dedicated server is used for game server and for my website) my root partition was full when the server still worked (`df -h`) but now I rebooted it and it stopped working os the technical support put it in rescue mode and gave me this.

```
Date 2016-11-02 09:51:43, Diagnosis interface boot (rescue): 
Here are the details of the operation performed: 
The server gets stuck during the boot phase. The following message is displayed: 

checking file systems... fsck from util-linux 2.20.1 
fsck.ext4:Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda2 
Could this be a zero-lenght partition? 
fsck died with exit status 8 
File system check failed. A log is being saved in /var/log/fsck/checkfs 
Location is writable. Please repair the file system manually 

A restart on the standard OVH kernel ('netboot') does not correct the 
situation. 

Actions: 
The SDD passed the SMART test and is correctly detected. 
Rebooting the server to "rescue" mode (Linux) 

result: 
Boot OK. Rescue mode accessible. 
2016-11-02 09:51:58    Rescue/KVM access codes sent 

recommendations: 
Configuration / error to be corrected by the customer. If you wish to work on your server while it is not accessible by the network, you could have a KVM installed for one day. For more information about this service, please contact our Technical Support.
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to try is to use the Rescue/KVM access codes that have been sent and access the system. From there you should, as the above says `repair the file system manually` by running fsck as appropriate.

Beyond that without knowing more details which are probably ony available from the rescue system there's not much we can do.

Aside: it looks like soyoustart are reselling OVH. In my opinion OVH is a hosting provider that only the experienced should choose.

Comment: What do you mean by fsck as appropriate?

Comment: I have access to the ssh rescue mode (is that what you mean?), i tried running cd or ls but that doesn't work fidsk does work though?

Comment: Could you fix this for me? (i will pay you?) you got skype?

Comment: soyoustart _is_ owned by OVH; it's one of their lower end services.

Comment: Micheal could you fix this?

Comment: I will pay you, i really need help and quickly :/

Comment: I am so desperate, should not have gone with a ovh sister company

Comment: @MichaelHampton ?

Comment: @Wearwolf Just install a new OS image on your server and restore from your backups. Fixing filesystem corruption is not worth spending time on.